# Change versions of binaries during install shield

Tags: versioning, installshield

Is it possible to change versions of dll and exe during install shield build? My project is in dotnet. Using single Assembly.cs or using variable does not helpful in my scenario.
I tried with IsCmdBld also but did not help. I want to change version in Assembly file and dll as well. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: "Dynamically" and "during InstallShield build" are opposite in meaning. Dynamically sounds like something you'd do during installation, or perhaps even later, and is probably a bad idea. But if you're asking how best to change version numbers of your binaries and installer during build, that's a reasonable question. Though it may have a duplicate answered already, and will need more details about your overall build system.

Comment: @MichaelUrman I have edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the version in the [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596(v=vs.85).aspx) table, but this is a really, really, really bad idea. I went down this road after bringing it up to the powers that be it was a bad idea, and I ended up paying for it with my job while trying to fix and recover from the road I told them not to take.

Long story short, just version your assemblies as part of your build process. there are plenty of scripting languages and libraries to update your resource files dynamically with your current version. Don't do this with InstallShield/MSI.